# c# WP ApplicationBar not showing MenuItems

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Okay, this is probably for a very stupid reason, but I can't get it.

I'm simply trying to add MenuItems to my WP app through XAML... but they don't show up in my app. I can see the IconButtons, but no MenuItem....

Am I missing something?
Is there maybe something that I need specify in the XAML first element?

```xml
<!-- Application Bar -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="applicationBar"
                          IsVisible="True"
                          IsMenuEnabled="False"
                          Opacity="0.7">

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Local" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Local.png" Click="ButtonLocal_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Global" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Global.png"  Click="ButtonGlobal_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Team" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Team.png"  Click="ButtonTeam_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Community" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Community.png" Click="ButtonCommunity_Click" />

        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="menu item 1" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="menu item 1" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the IsMenuEnabled to True, as shown:

```xml
<!-- Application Bar -->
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="applicationBar" 
                          IsVisible="True"
                          IsMenuEnabled="True"
                          Opacity="0.7">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Local" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Local.png" Click="ButtonLocal_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Global" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Global.png" Click="ButtonGlobal_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Team" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Team.png" Click="ButtonTeam_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Community" IconUri="/Resources/Icons/ApplicationBar/Community.png" Click="ButtonCommunity_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="menu item 1" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="menu item 1" /></shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: ^_^'''' lol. I feel quite stupid. I thought I already checked those attributes, and they were all set on true....but they apparently weren't! thanks

Comment: No problem, easy to miss

Answer (score 3):

```
IsMenuEnabled="False"
```

Set it to true, it'll be way better ;)